# Can a registrar outage affect my website?

Tags: domain-registrar

If my registrar has an outage and their servers go down for a while, will that affect my website.  I'm not using any of my registrar hosting packages or name servers, I simply have a few domain names registered with them that point to my actual hosting provider.

Based on my current understanding on how these things work I believe that an outage at my registrar will not affect my websites at all, but I'd like to hear this from someone with more experience in this field.

Answer (score 1):

The only way your registrar's outage would affect your website is if they manage your DNS as well.

If you host your DNS, or have your DNS hosted by a third party, or that portion of the registrar's network is not down, then your web site should be unaffected.

Comment: Well even if you're hosting your own DNS you still need to setup custom name servers in your registrar. If their DNS servers managing the custom name servers are affected it'll affect routing to your domain.